# Calculating a Cauchy principal value

Tags: integration, limits, improper-integrals, distribution-theory

I need to compute the following integral:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x+i\epsilon}.
\end{equation}
Applying the Sokhotski-Plemelj theorem, we have
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x+i\epsilon} = \mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x}-i\pi.
\end{equation}
I am wondering how the Cauchy principal value is defined in this case when we have a singularity at finite value as well as at infinity. My book tells me that the Cauchy principal value equals zero, but I do not see why.

I have already tried the usual definition, but it is not applicable because both integrals are divergent:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x} = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x}+\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Hint: use the fact that $x \mapsto 1/x$ is an odd function by doing a substitution $x \to -x$.

Comment: Why do you want to compute that integral? From where did you get it? It is indeed divergent as such, but if we want to be a bit incautious then we can say that $\mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x = 0$ so that we get $-i\pi$ as a result.

Comment: This limit is also called the Cauchy principal value:
$$\lim_{A \to \infty} \int_{-A}^A \frac {dx} {x + i \epsilon}.$$
The limit is equal to $-\pi i$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: @Héhéhé: Taking a look at Wikipedia, I realised that one has to be careful when doing substitutions in context with a principal value. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @md2perpe: Those integrals arise naturally when calculating self-energies in quantum field theory. I have now found out that there is a definition on Wikipedia for that case: \begin{equation} \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left[ \int_{b-\frac{1}{\epsilon}}^{b-\epsilon} f(x) dx +  \int_{b+\epsilon}^{b+\frac{1}{\epsilon}} f(x) dx\right] \end{equation} This would give me 0 without being incautious. Do you think this is applicable here?

Comment: @Maxim: I know that this is the definition for the case of a singularity at infinity. In my case, I also have a singularity at a finite number, so this definition is not applicable.

Comment: @md2perpe: For example, it is also stated in the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787732/integration-of-a-divergent-integral-using-the-cauchy-principal-value?rq=1), where Szeto states it as a well-known result.

Comment: Yeah you should use the definition of Wikipedia.